# DRF, use method for read, and field for write

Tags: django-rest-framework

Say you have a `quantity` field in your order model.

You have `get_quantity` method which you want to use for `read` (serializing).
At the same time, you want to use `quantity` field to create or update.

```
quantity = serializers.IntegerField(source="get_quantity", required=False)
```

fails to use `quantity` when `writing`.

How to do something like

```
read_source="get_quantity"
write_source="quantity"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Method - 1: override the **`to_representation(...)`** method

```py
class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(required=False) # do not set `source` parameter

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep["quantity"] = instance.get_quantity()
        return rep
```

#### Method - 2: Use two different serializer

```py
class FooReadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, source="get_quantity")


class FooWriteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```